# R: gsub inserting whitespaces between capture groups

Tags: regex, r

I'm desperately trying to insert whitespaces between capture groups. My naive approach was

```
c = c("WesternSaharaRegion", "ColumbiaState", "OneTwoThreeFourFiveSix")
gsub("(.+[a-z])([A-Z].+)","\\1 \\2", clist, perl=T)
```

which is only inserting a whitespaces between the last two capital-letter-words. Using

```
gsub("(?=([a-z][A-Z]))"," ", c, perl = T)
```

works not quite exactly for it's a one-character-shifted version

```
"Wester nSahar aRegion"       "Columbi aState"              "On eTw oThre eFou rFiv eSix"
```

How am I able to *elegantly* receive

```
    "Western Sahara Region"       "Columbia State"              "One Two Three Four Five Six"
```

strsplit() unfortunately doesn't keep the capture group :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can either use regex lookarounds

```
 gsub('(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', ' ', c, perl=TRUE)
 #[1] "Western Sahara Region"       "Columbia State"              "One Two Three Four Five Six"
```

Or use capture groups

```
gsub('([a-z])([A-Z])', '\\1 \\2', c)
#[1] "Western Sahara Region"       "Columbia State"              "One Two Three Four Five Six"
```

Comment: Jep, done. Your answer helped me to finally get my head around 'lookarounds', thank you.