# How to use mutate to create multiple variables with regex

Tags: r, regex, function, data.table, tidyverse

I want to create new variables using `paste0` by performing operation on other variables also using `paste0`. My approach fails as it only pastes the names of the new variables as observations, without generating the actual values. Thanks in advance for any help.

**My data:**

```
tempDF <- structure(list(d1 = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "C"), d2 = c(40L, 50L, 20L, 50L, 20L), 
        d3 = c(20L, 40L, 50L, 40L, 50L), d4 = c(60L, 30L, 30L,60L, 30L), p_A = c(1L, 
        3L, 2L, 3L, 2L), p_B = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L), p_C = c(2L, 1L, 1L,2L, 1L), p4 = c(5L, 
        5L, 4L, 5L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

tempDF$d1 <- stats::relevel(as.factor(tempDF$d1), ref = "A")      
lLevels<-levels(tempDF$d1)


View(tempDF)
```

**My attempt**

```
func<-function(tempDF, lLevels){

for(aLevelNum in seq_along(lLevels)){

tempDF_new<-tempDF%>%
  mutate(paste0("newp_", lLevels[aLevelNum], "_vs_", lLevels[1])=d2*paste0("p", "_", lLevels[aLevelNum])))%>%
  dplyr::select(-contains(paste0("newp_", lLevels[1], "_vs_", lLevels[1])))%>%
        as.data.frame(.)



}

return(tempDF_new)      

}

tempDF_new<-func(tempDF, lLevels) %>%
        as.data.frame(.)

View(tempDF_new)
```

**Expected output**

```
tempDF_new
  d1 d2 d3 d4 p_A p_B p_C p4 newp_B_vs_A newp_C_vs_A
1  A 40 20 60   1   3   2  5 120         80
2  B 50 40 30   3   4   1  5 200         50
3  C 20 50 30   2   3   1  4 60          20
4  A 50 40 60   3   3   2  5 150         100
5  C 20 50 30   2   4   1  4 80          20
```

Comment: Can you please describe what should be done? How are your new variables created?

Comment: By multiplying `d2` with `paste0("p", "_", lLevels[aLevelNum])))`  for each `(aLevelNum in seq_along(lLevels))`. The resulting variable each time is given the name `paste0("newp_", lLevels[aLevelNum], "_vs_", lLevels[1])`

Comment: Is this giving you the expected output `tempDF %>%
 mutate_at(vars(starts_with("p_")), list(vs_d2 = ~ . * d2))`?

Comment: Thanks. Let me test.

Comment: Great. It works. Thank you. But does not name the resulting variables as expected. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure how your variables are supposed to be named.

Comment: Hi, @tmfmnk. The renaming is done by `paste0("newp_", lLevels[aLevelNum], "_vs_", lLevels[1])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to get the desired names

```
 library(dplyr)
 tempDF %>% 
        mutate_at(vars('p_B','p_C'), list(newp = ~d2*.)) %>% 
        #create two groups then flip them, put _ in the middle and add _vs_A at the end 
        #For groups in gsub see e.g 
        #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463256/r-gsub-inserting-whitespaces-between-capture-groups
        rename_at(vars(ends_with('newp')), ~gsub('p_(.*)_(newp)','\\2_\\1_vs_A',.))

 d1 d2 d3 d4 p_A p_B p_C p4 newp_B_vs_A newp_C_vs_A
1  A 40 20 60   1   3   2  5         120          80
2  B 50 40 30   3   4   1  5         200          50
3  C 20 50 30   2   3   1  4          60          20
4  A 50 40 60   3   3   2  5         150         100
5  C 20 50 30   2   4   1  4          80          20
```

## Update

```
#Replace map_dfc with map if you need a list 
library(purrr)
res <- map2_dfc(unique(tempDF$d1), c('d2','d3','d4'), function(x,y) {
  #In the 1st iter it will be B|C, the 2nd C|A
  conds <- paste(setdiff(unique(tempDF$d1), x), collapse = "|")

  #y it will be d1, d2, d3
  #x it will be A, B, C
  tmp <- select(tempDF, y, matches(conds)) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(matches(conds)), list(newp=~!!sym(y)*.))%>%
    rename_at(vars(ends_with('newp')), list(~gsub('p_(.*)_(newp)', paste0('\\2_\\1_vs_',x), .))) %>% 
    select(ends_with(x))
})

bind_cols(tempDF, res)



d1 d2 d3 d4 p_A p_B p_C p4 newp_B_vs_A newp_C_vs_A newp_A_vs_B newp_C_vs_B newp_A_vs_C newp_B_vs_C
1  A 40 20 60   1   3   2  5         120          80          20          40          60         180
2  B 50 40 30   3   4   1  5         200          50         120          40          90         120
3  C 20 50 30   2   3   1  4          60          20         100          50          60          90
4  A 50 40 60   3   3   2  5         150         100         120          80         180         180
5  C 20 50 30   2   4   1  4          80          20         100          50          60         120
```

Comment: @Krantz see my update, probably you need something like this given your last question.

Answer (score 1):

This had a data.table tag. But features tidyverse answers. In rdata.table:

`DT[, newvar:= paste0(var1/var2)]`  would create a character field from the original numeric op.

`DT[, newvar:= var1/var2 ]` would create a numeric field if var1 and var2 were integer or numeric.

help(set) walks you through what is functionally the insert operator (':=')  This operator is optimized, fast, flexible.